# Venn diagrams, relative so size of its content

Tags: tikz-pgf, venn-diagrams

Now I am looking if there is any easy way to create venn-diagrams where the circles/ellipses change size relative to its content. 
I am basically looking for simple compliments either on the form

[image: [\img]https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Irn9.gif[img]] or with three elements

The output I am looking for is somewhat along these lines
[image]

Where the size of the circles are relative to their percentages or probability.
(Larger circles, larger probability) and the largest circle represents 1 or 100%

Now is it possible creating a macro that allows one to create such images? 
Example, given that A=40 , B=60 , A \cap B = 20

Comment: In principle yes, but the [math will be horrible](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleIntersection.html)

Comment: Horrible? You are speaking to a math undergrad ;)
I am sure a solution can be aquired using the \calc package.

Comment: Horrible. Try solving for d in equation (14) in http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleIntersection.html

Comment: I did, gave me 4 solutions. However latex was not able to interpret the input, I probably did something wrong.

Comment: [I tried to ask WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+A%3Dr^2+cos^-1%28%28d^2%2Br^2-R^2%29%2F%282+d+r%29%29%2BR^2cos^-1%28%28d^2-r^2%2BR^2%29%2F%282+d+R%29%29-1%2F2*%28%28-d%2Br%2BR%29%28d%2Br-R%29%28d-r%2BR%29%28d%2Br%2BR%29%29^0.5+for+d), but without a pro account this is to intense :(

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/Q4u7u.png

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar: You're trying to solve the wrong equation: _a_ is the "chord connecting the cusps of the lens". The equation you're looking for is further down, equation (14). As this contains both terms like d^n and cos^-1((r^2-d^2)/d) it's very likely you won't be able to find an analytic solution...

Comment: Probably one could use an iterative approach via nesting intervals, but heavy math computation is one of LaTeX's strong suits. Do you need it on the fly (e.g. inside LaTeX) or can you use Maple for approximating a solution and insert it manually?

Comment: Recommend that you consider using rectangles instead of circles.  Because there are many combination which cannot be displayed with circles.  eg Sample space=100  A=60, B=40, A \cap B =20; cannot be done with circles.   Additionally the computations with rectangles will be trivial.

Comment: it should be possible with PSTricks, because the math is no Problem for PostScript. But I have for 4 weeks no machine with a running TeX ... so an answer will be possible in august.

Comment: The center points of completely-enclosed circles are free to move?

Comment: Yes, and I must not have circles either. A bit later I will add an answer containing squares (much easier). But I guess ellipsis should work too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is "impossible". You can't draw circles with the requested values : A=.40 , B=.60 , A \cap B = .20 like R. Schumacher wrote.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{tikz,verbatim}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,patterns}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4,>=latex']
  \draw[magenta] circle[radius=1cm]; 
  \node[above right,magenta] at (0,1) {$\mathcal{C}$};  
  \draw (0.63245-1,0) circle [radius=0.63245cm];   % sqrt(0.4) 
  \draw (1-0.77459,0) circle [radius=0.77459cm];   % sqrt(0.6)
  \node[above right] at (-1,0) {$\mathcal{C}_a$};
  \node[above left] at ( 1,0) {$\mathcal{C}_b$};
  \draw[->] (-1,0)--(1.2,0); 
  \draw[->] (0,-1)--(0,1.2);
  \filldraw[blue] (0.63245-1,0) circle(.4pt) -- node[above right]{$ra\approx 0.632$}++(60:0.63245); 
  \filldraw[blue] (1-0.77459,0) circle(.4pt) -- node[above right]{$rb\approx 0.774$}++(60:0.77459);
    \draw[magenta,<->] (0,0) -- node[below]{1} (1,0);  
   \clip (0.63245-1,0) circle [radius=0.63245cm];   % sqrt(0.4) 
   \clip (1-0.77459,0) circle [radius=0.77459cm];   % sqrt(0.6)
   \fill[pattern=north east lines,fill opacity=.5]  circle[radius=1cm];
   \draw[red,<->] (0.63245-1,-0.05) -- node[below]{0.59296} (1-0.77459,-0.05);

   \node at (-0.25,-0.4){$\mathcal{A}$};     
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{verbatim}
Macro to determine the area of the asymmetric lens.
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ra}{sqrt(0.4)} 
\pgfmathsetmacro{\rb}{sqrt(0.6)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\d}{2-0.63245-0.77459}    
\pgfmathsetmacro{\area}{%
   (  \ra*\ra*acos((\d*\d-\rb*\rb+\ra*\ra)/(2*\d*\ra))/180*3.1415     
     +\rb*\rb*acos((\d*\d+\rb*\rb-\ra*\ra)/(2*\d*\rb))/180*3.1415
     -0.5*sqrt((-\d+\ra+\rb)*(\d+\ra-\rb)*(\d-\ra+\rb)*(\d+\ra+\rb))
     )/3.1415}  
\end{verbatim} 

\pgfmathsetmacro{\d}{2-0.63245-0.77459} 
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ra}{sqrt(0.4)} 
\pgfmathsetmacro{\rb}{sqrt(0.6)}   
\pgfmathsetmacro{\area}{%
   (  \ra*\ra*acos((\d*\d-\rb*\rb+\ra*\ra)/(2*\d*\ra))/180*3.1415     
     +\rb*\rb*acos((\d*\d+\rb*\rb-\ra*\ra)/(2*\d*\rb))/180*3.1415
     -0.5*sqrt((-\d+\ra+\rb)*(\d+\ra-\rb)*(\d-\ra+\rb)*(\d+\ra+\rb))
     )/3.1415}  

The area of the circle $\mathcal{C}$  is $1\times \pi$.

The area of the circle $\mathcal{C}_a$  is $0.4\times \pi$.

The area of the circle $\mathcal{C}_b$  is $0.6\times \pi$.   

If $d=0.59296$  then $\mathcal{A}=\area\times \pi$.


\pgfmathsetmacro{\d}{0.681}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\area}{%
   (  \ra*\ra*acos((\d*\d-\rb*\rb+\ra*\ra)/(2*\d*\ra))/180*3.1415     
     +\rb*\rb*acos((\d*\d+\rb*\rb-\ra*\ra)/(2*\d*\rb))/180*3.1415
     -0.5*sqrt((-\d+\ra+\rb)*(\d+\ra-\rb)*(\d-\ra+\rb)*(\d+\ra+\rb))
     )/3.1415} 

If $d=0.681$  then $\mathcal{A}=\area\times \pi$ but  $0.59296$  is the maximum value of $d$, so it's impossible to draw circles with the requested values.

\end{document}
```

For others values it's possible to  use an iterative approach via nesting intervals (dichotomy) . I find `0.681` with a manual approach  but I think it's not very difficult to build an algorithm to find this value.